# Error when using yeoman to generate angular app: unhandled Template render error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I want to use yeoman to generate an angular app structure, but an error stopped me.

`yo-->Angular Bootstrap-->more options-->`

**error occurs:**

```
Possibly unhandled Template render error: (unknown path) [Line 3, Column 90]
  expected variable end
    at Object.exports.withPrettyErrors (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:33:17)
    at Obj.extend.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:344:20)
    at Obj.extend.renderString (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:231:21)
    at Generator.engine [as _engine] (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/app/modules/nunjucks-engine.js:17:14)
    at Generator.engine (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:314:10)
    at Generator.template (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:289:15)
    at setupAppFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/app/index.js:209:10)
    at tryCatch1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:45:21)
    at Promise$_callHandler [as _callHandler] (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:658:13)
    at Promise$_settlePromiseFromHandler [as _settlePromiseFromHandler] (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-bootstrap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:672:18)
```

So, anyone can help me?

Comment: I am also having this same issue.

Comment: Are you on a mac. If so, I might at least have tracked down the source of the issue.

Comment: In file included from ../fsevents.cc:86:
../src/constants.cc:10:66: warning: template argument uses unnamed type [-Wunnamed-type-template-args]
  object->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone"), NanNew<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));

Comment: The above appears to come from the nunjucks module...whatever that is. :)

Comment: When then seems to be an issue coming from here....the maintainer of that code base closed the issue as fixed...but as we can see...it is not. :)

https://github.com/pipobscure/fsevents/issues/33

Comment: My os is `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`.

Comment: https://github.com/mgcrea/generator-angular-bootstrap/issues/18

Answer (score 10):

**I've "solved" by downgrading the version from 0.5.1 to 0.4.3:**

```
$ sudo npm uninstall -g generator-angular-bootstrap
$ sudo npm install -g generator-angular-bootstrap@0.4.3
$ yo angular-bootstrap
```

This error seems to be related to `nunjucks` -- which was introduced [in version 0.5.0](https://github.com/mgcrea/generator-angular-bootstrap/commit/d089cd49f44b45746ae2c9f0ac071a9da3588c33) (I've experienced the error in 0.5.0 and 0.5.1); and probably related to something else I couldn't identify quickly.

Comment: I'd give this a green check mark if I could. Thanks!

Comment: That worked! There seems to be more and more confusion and discrepancy between packages within the yeoman generator sphere; one now discover "problems" like the above *all* *the* *time*. The whole point was to automatize such trivial tasks, but now we have the huge task to figure out and recover from various grunt / yeoman / generator failures instead :(

Answer (score 0):

delete **/usr/lib/node_modules** and install all dependencies again following this tutorial: http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html

After that you could run **"yo angular"** and choose Bootstrap as one of dependecies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this does not work. 'yo angular' has always worked just fine. the issue is when trying to run 'yo angular-bootstrap' which apparently has a different type of scaffolding mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know you got the answer, but you can probably go with default project generation, which has bootstrap itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this does not work. 'yo angular' has always worked just fine. the issue is when trying to run 'yo angular-bootstrap' which apparently has a different type of scaffolding mechanism. And the reason for wanting to use this scaffold is it provides an option to support angular on IE<9.